# Converting a 13 digit Unix timestamp to DateTime with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert this 13 digit Unix timestamp (1563398686957) to YYYYMMDD format using Javascript. How can I do this?

I have divided the 1563398686957/1000 and tried to get the first 10 digits but converting from Number to String and back gives me an error and is not there right way to do it if I am looping for many timestamps.

```
var newCreateDate = 1563398686957 / 1000;
var newTimestamp = Array();
for (let i = 0; i < newCreateDate.length; i++) {
    temp_timestamp = String(newCreateDate[i].slice(0, 9));
    newTimestamp.push(Number(temp_timestamp));
}
```

Comment: Have a look this `URL` I hope it's helpful https://www.toptal.com/software/definitive-guide-to-datetime-manipulation

Comment: [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor may receive exactly 13 digit Unix timestamp as a parameter).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass timestamp into `Date`:

```js
var unixts = 1563398686957;
var date = new Date(unixts);

var fdate = date.getFullYear() + '/' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
console.log(fdate);
```

Comment: @kshetline true

Answer (score 1):

`new Date(1563398686957).toISOString().substr(0, 10)`

Will give you the date in this form: `2019-07-17`

`new Date(1563398686957).toISOString().substr(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/')`

Will change the dashes to slashes, if you prefer, and...

`new Date(1563398686957).toISOString().substr(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '')`

Would give you `20190717`.

Comment: short and great